# Is the minimum of two supermodular functions supermodular?

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are [supermodular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermodular_function), non-negative and increasing set functions. Is the function $$h(X)=\min(f(X),g(X))$$ supermodular? What about the maximum?

Comment: What does supermodular mean?

Comment: I added a link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermodular_function but upon re-reading, I wonder if that is what you meant, since you also talk about "set functions"... Please clarify your question by adding a definition of the notion you are referring to, to avoid any ambiguity.

Comment: @MaxHorn, note that, despite the section title saying 'submodular', the same Wiki article discusses [supermodularity of functions of a set argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermodular_function#Submodular_functions_of_subsets).

Comment: @LSpice Yes, I noticed. Which is why I commented, asking for a clarification

Answer (score 2):

This is a counterexample to the $\textit{min}$ question.
Consider the universe $X=\{1,..,5\}.$

Let $f,g \in \mathbb{Z}^{\mathcal{P}(X)}$ be defined as follows: $$ f(S)= (\lvert X \rvert + \lvert S \rvert) \cdot \mathbb{1}_{\lvert S \rvert \geq 3 } \hspace{2mm} and \hspace{2mm} g(S)=\lvert S \rvert $$. 
With $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{1,2,4\}$, the inequality $$ 6  = min(f(A),g(A)) +  min(f(B),g(B)) \leq min(f(A\cap B),g(A \cap B))+ min (f(A \cup B), g(A \cup B)) = 4 $$ is untrue.

This is a counterexample to the $\textit{max}$ question. Consider the universe $X=\{1,2,3\}.$ Let $f,g \in \mathbb{Z}^{\mathcal{P}(X)}$ be defined as follows: $$f(S)=\mathbb{1}_{\{1 \in S\}} \hspace{2mm} and \hspace{2mm} g(S)= \mathbb{1}_{\{3 \in S\}}.$$

Now let $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{2,3\}$.

The inequality $$ 2 = max(f(A),g(A)) +  max(f(B),g(B)) \leq max(f(A\cap B),g(A \cap B))+ max (f(A \cup B), g(A \cup B)) = 1 $$ is untrue.

Consequently, the answer to both questions is no. (I assumed that you meant 'non-decreasing' instead of 'increasing'.)

In 'Submodular functions and convexity', L. Lovász gives a sufficient condition for the minimum of two submodular set functions to be submodular: if $f$ and $g$ are submodular set functions such that $f-g$ is either monotone increasing or decreasing, then $min(f,g)$ is also submodular. The condition applies to supermodularity by substituting supermodular for submodular and $\textit{max}$ for $\textit{min}$.